# How to crash app inside RxJava map operator

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android

When, for example, a NullPointerException occurs after calling the RxJava map operator, the app doesn't crash. I want the app to crash when this happens so it can submit reports to crashlytics etc.

I tried using `Exceptions.propagate()` in a try/catch block but that didn't work.

The only solution that I found was throwing a `RuntimeException` in my error handler.

```
    override fun getCategories(): Single<List<Category>> {
        return ApiManager
                .getCategoriesService()
                .getCategories()
                .map { categoriesResponse ->
                        throw KotlinNullPointerException
                        categoriesResponse.categories?.map { categoryResponse ->
                            CategoryMapper().mapFromRemote(categoryResponse)
                        }
                }
    }
```

The NullPointerException thrown inside the map operator does not crash the app.
If I call it before the return statement it crashes the app.

Comment: who's subscribing to this, and how? you're likely catching the NPE in the throwable area of the subscription, which basically operates like a "try/catch" causing it to not crash

Comment: also, why are you trying to make the app crash? you may not have a good use case for what rxjava is intended to do (which is to do everything possible to not crash)

Comment: This i called by an UseCase in the Domain Layer, which in turn is being called from a ViewModel , with  `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`.  
For development purposes mainly, when there is a problem in the mapper, p.e a NullPointerException, it is not displayed in the logcat.

Comment: > you're likely catching the NPE in the throwable area of the subscription, which basically operates like a "try/catch" causing it to not crash

How do I circumvent this? I want errors to be displayed on the logcat for example, so I can understand where was the problem in my Mapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I call it before the return statement it crashes the app.

It crashes because `getCategories` method is running on Android's main thread to build the rx chain.

> The NullPointerException thrown inside the map operator does not crash the app.

It doesn't crash the app because this chain is being subscribed to a thread that is not Android's main thread. E.g. your chain has `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`.

> The only solution that I found was throwing a RuntimeException in my error handler.

That's the expected design of your chain as per this [document](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling):

> An Observable typically does not throw exceptions. Instead it notifies any observers that an unrecoverable error has occurred by terminating the Observable sequence with an onError notification.
>
> So rather than catch exceptions, your observer or operator should more typically respond to onError notifications of exceptions.

Comment: >... getCategories method is running on Android's main thread
>... this chain is being observed on a thread that is not Android's main thread.

`getCategories` is called by an UseCase directly with `repository.getCategories()` . This UseCase is called from a ViewModel like this `getCategoriesUseCase.execute().subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(::onCategorySuccess, ::onCategoryError)`
I thought that meant `getCategories` was running in the thread specified in `subscribeOn` and being observed in the main thread?

Comment: yes, you are correct, sorry for the confusion, I updated my answer

Comment: So about your first statement, that `getCategories` is running on the main thread and that's why it crashes, how is that possible if it's subscribed in an IO thread?

Comment: `getCategories` method only builds the rx chain, it doesn't actually run the tasks of the chain. For example, if you just call `getCategories` (without calling `subscribe`), the code inside the `map` operator won't run. It only runs when you subscribe to the chain with the `subscribe` method. Then you can chose to subscribe on IO thread. But the code to build the chain, inside `getCategories` is still running from the main thread (if called from the main thread).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think the closest to what I want to achieve is by calling `Exceptions.propagate(throwable)` in the error handler called in onError. 
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Gustavo @TooManyEduardos2